# Celery group multiple tasks in one design

Tags: django, redis, celery

I just getting familiar with Celery and have a question. My setup is Django-Redis-Celery

Lets take an example of a task sending email:

**TASKS**

```
@task
def send_email(message):
   mailserver.sendOneMessage(message)
```

**VIEWS**

```
class newaccount(APIView):
  def post(self, request, format=None): 
    send_email.delay(request.data.email)
```

This works perfectly, Django sends messages to Redis and those are picked up by Celery then to execute task. But I want to improve the system so that Celery picks up all messages from Redis at certain intervals and executes a single task with multiple messages. This because, connecting to the email server is slow and sending multiple messages as a single request will result in a faster process.

I want something like this to work:

**TASKS**

```
@task
def send_emails(messages):
   mailserver.sendMultipleMessages(messages)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried passing to the task an array of emails, and then looping in the task to send those e-mails ?

Comment: @Niloct That is not possible. Emails are added at user authorization step. I guess can group them later manually using redis and periodic celery tasks, but I am not sure how to correctly design that.

Answer (score 3):

Since i am using redis as a cache (django-redis) already i implemented the following workflow:

Step 1. Create a task that adds new emails to cache

```
@shared_task()
def add_email(user_id):
   cache.set("email#{}".format(user_id), None, timeout=None)
```

Step 2. Create a periodic task that runs every second and looks up for new emails in the cache

```
class ProcessEmailsTask(PeriodicTask):
   run_every = timedelta(seconds=1)

   def run(self, **kwargs):
       call_email()

def call_email():
   item_exists = True
   ids = []
   while item_exists:
    try:
        key = next(cache.iter_keys("email#*"))
        ids.append(key.split("email#")[1])
        cache.delete_pattern(key)
    except:
        item_exists = False
   if len(ids) > 0:
        send_emails_to(ids)
```

Step 3. Run both celery workers and celery beat and profit!

Comment: This is basically implementing your own queue and more than 4 years later I am dealing with the same issue. I'm trying to find a way to get Celery to do that for me: after all, rabbitMQ does it by design. Have you found a better solution or is this still the way you handle this problem?